# Compiling projects in different configurations in a multi-projects Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a visual studio solution containing multiple projects. Just to simplify the testing, I have created 2 sub-projects. I need to compile and run ***one sub-project in Win-32*** configuration because it uses an external DLL (win-32 config) and ***another sub-project in x64***.

How can I do that?

[image]

**UPDATE-1:** I already tried to set the configuration of both the projects as shown in the screenshot below. But as soon as I build the proect then both the projects are build in the configuration which is selected in the main window.

[image]

Comment: Try to add a own configuration and override Debug or Release, make one for Win32 and one for x64. Maybe this works

Comment: [To build multiple solution configurations at once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-multiple-platforms?view=vs-2019#to-build-multiple-solution-configurations-at-once)
1,Use the Configuration Manager to add at least two target platforms for the solution.
2,Use the Batch Build window to build several solution configurations at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Configuration Manager (menu `Build > Configuration manager`). There, you can set the configuration and platform for individual projects for each solution configuration+platform pair.

Comment: I did that but as I updated in my OP, as soon as I build the project, both the projects are compiled in the configuration which is selected at that time in the main window.